# Using business software development concepts in game development?

Tags: design-patterns, language-agnostic

Over the past few years I had the chance to develop “business” software applications including mobile apps, backend systems and frontend applications for which many different principles and concepts were used such as object-relational mapping, reactive programming, dependency injection, Model-View-Controller-Pattern and many more.

While getting started with some game programming I wonder how some of those concepts can be used for developing games. For example when programming a world builder game like Anno 1602 (1602 A.D.) I can imagine implementing production buildings as microservices.

My question is about thinking outside of the box; it is not important whether using some concept could have a serious performance impact for the game or not.

*What concepts used in non-game application programming could be used for game development and in which way?*

Answer (score 0):

For example you can use GoF [Design Patterns](http://www.design-patterns-stories.com) like State for taking care about the states, creational patterns for objects creation, FlyWeight to save memory, Proxy to load heavy objects on demand, etc., details about design patterns for game dev can be founded [here](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/design-patterns-revisited.html)

Answer (score 0):

Games tend to have more sophisticated graphics, less standardized user interfaces and sometimes require more complex calculations than most business applications. But aside from that, there is no significant difference.

So why should there be any rules for business applications that don't apply to games?